# A stopwatch with React and setInterval: how to fix the missing timer id issue?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I'm trying to create a stopwatch in a React app. Inside a component (well, currently inside `App()` created with vite), I have the following bits:

```
const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0)

// this was just timer: number | undefined, which I've changed to this,
// but it didn't help, keep reading
let timer: { id?: number } = {
    id: undefined,
}
const tickSecond = () => setElapsedTime(prevElapsedTime => prevElapsedTime + 1)
const resumeClock = () => timer.id = window.setInterval(tickSecond, 1000)
const pauseClock = () => {
    window.clearInterval(timer.id)
    timer.id = undefined
}
const toggleClockRun = () => {
    console.log(`toggleClockRun: timer is`,timer)
    timer.id ? pauseClock() : resumeClock()
}
const startClock = () => {
    setElapsedTime(0)
    resumeClock()
    console.log(`startClock: timer is`,timer)
}
```

and in JSX:

```
<button onClick={startClock}>start</button>
<button onClick={toggleClockRun}>pause</button>
```

The expected behavior would be:

- click `start` starts the stopwatch;
- click `pause` pauses it (well, toggles pause, but it's not important in this context).

While `startClock` reports `startClock: timer is {id: 35}` (evaluated at the point of logging), `toggleClockRun` unexpectedly reports `startClock: timer is {id: undefined}`. How comes? Both when storing the timer id inside `timer` as a number (`timer = window.setInterval(..)`) or as the `id` property of `{id}`, inside `toggleClockRun` although there's no other assigning of its value. Why `timer.id` becomes `undefined`?

PS For debugging, I've also tried to add `{timer.id}` to JSX, and it never shown a non-empty value (but that's probably because editing the value didn't cause re-rendering).

Comment: Every time something is rerendered you are going to lose everything that is not in some kind of state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer reference needs to be persisted between renders. The `useRef` hook is used to store values that do not cause a re-render when updated.

```
const {useReducer, useRef} = React;

function reducer(currentState, newState) {
  return {...currentState, ...newState};
}

function Stopwatch() {
  const [{running, lapsedTime}, setState] = useReducer(reducer, {
    running: false,
    lapsedTime: 0,
  });

  const timerRef = useRef(null);

  function toggleClockRun() {
    if (running) {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    } else {
      const startTime = Date.now() - lapsedTime;
      timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setState({lapsedTime: Date.now() - startTime});
      }, 0)
    }
    setState({running: !running});
  }

  function resetButtonClick() {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    setState({lapsedTime: 0, running: false});
  }

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
      <label
        style={{
          display: 'block',
        }}
      >
        {lapsedTime}
      </label>
      <button onClick={toggleClockRun}>
        {running ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
      </button>
      <button onClick={resetButtonClick}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Stopwatch />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Thanks, Wow, the stopwatch is even the example they use in docs: https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef; for TS, needed to define it as `useRef<number | null>(null)` though